# Invert Voltage 0-2V

Tags: voltage-regulator, voltage-divider, voltage-measurement

I need to invert voltage from the one sensor.
So the ting is that I have DC signal from sensor:
0%-100% range of 0V-2V
I need:
0%-100% range of 2V-0V

I have LM324 level indicator and it is showing opposite value, I can not connect opposite inputs on LM because circuit board is done.

Any idea how to do it as simple as possible?

It is a simple one measuring device, 10 input channels - OP amps, working on a 12V. OP amp is comparing common input signal (0V-2V) and each OP has its own referral voltage. Only case is that it is working opposite showing full tank when is is empty and vice versa. So I need to figure out how to invert voltage from the sensor as i mention above... supply is same for sensor and device 12VDC, and it is common (-), otherwise it would be possible with few resistors

Comment: Welcome!! But you need to add more information about your application, some schematics of the relevant sections would help. How do you plan to invert a signal without adding circuitry (i.e., you say your PCB is done) the LM324 is an OP-amp not a "level indicator." Is your input single-ended or is it somehow differential? Is your sensor signal self-powered or are you somehow applying power?

Comment: Not as simply as cutting and jumpering your LM324.  Unless you have power available and can equip yourself with an external board with a biased inverting op-amp circuit.

Comment: I don't have drawing, and it is a bit hard to make hand drawing. Device is factory assembled I need to reconnect it...

Comment: There is a schematic button on the editor toolbar. It saves an inline, editable and copy-able schematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This circuit inverts the 0V-2V voltage source to 2V-0V.

[image: schematic]

Comment: Thank You Stefan, is it somehow possible to make it without AC supply?

Comment: This is not AC supply. I used an AC waveform with voltage from 0V to 2V to test this circuit. So this AC thing is where you connect your sensor output.

Comment: Ok I understand now, and what OP is here in use?

Comment: Basically, it doesn‘t matter which OP. (You can use the LM324).